# Python: Parsing a String to create comma separated values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have string as below and i want to parse this string and get the values after `=` in the string as a comma seperated values.

```
string = "TimeStamp=[2017-03-07 00:22:12.697Z] RequestUri=https://google.com SessionId={null} UserId=8273527 VisitorId= UserAgent=\"Abc Proxy\" SystemType=Connect ClientIp=140.11.135.123 IsTestSystem=False"
```

Expected Output:

```
'[2017-03-07 00:22:12.697Z]','https://google.com','{null}','8273527','','Abc Proxy','Connect','140.11.135.123','False'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could start with `your_string.split("=")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not that well formatted, you have spaces in some of your values, and you have some data without a value. Because of that it wouldn't be very easy in pure python, so I'd use `re` instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\w+\=', string)
['', '[2017-03-07 00:22:12.697Z] ', 'https://google.com ', '{null} ', '8273527 ', ' ', '"Abc Proxy" ', 'Connect ', '140.11.135.123 ', 'False']
```

You can add a check for empty strings with list comprehension:

```
>>> [x.strip() for x in re.split(r'\w+\=', string) if x.strip()]
['[2017-03-07 00:22:12.697Z]', 'https://google.com', '{null}', '8273527', '"Abc Proxy"', 'Connect', '140.11.135.123', 'False']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to use `str.split` method:

```
s = "TimeStamp=[2017-03-07 00:22:12.697Z] RequestUri=https://google.com SessionId={null} UserId=8273527 VisitorId= UserAgent=\"Abc Proxy\" SystemType=Connect ClientIp=140.11.135.123 IsTestSystem=False"
print [i.split("=")[-1] for i in s.split()]
```

Output:

```
['[2017-03-07', '00:22:12.697Z]', 'https://google.com', '{null}', '8273527', '', '"Abc', 'Proxy"', 'Connect', '140.11.135.123', 'False']
```

Maybe the timestamp is not you want,so try this:

```
first_split = s.split("]", 1)
print ["["+first_split[0].split("[")[-1]+"]"] + [i.split("=")[-1] for i in first_split[1].split()]
```

Output:

```
['[2017-03-07 00:22:12.697Z]', 'https://google.com', '{null}', '8273527', '', '"Abc', 'Proxy"', 'Connect', '140.11.135.123', 'False']
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Python way. It has limitation that it assumes that key contains no space (the answer using regex  has this limitation too).

```
output = []
for token in string.split(' '):
    if '=' in token:
        output.append(token.split('=')[1])
    else:
        output.append(output.pop() + ' ' + token)

print output
```

Comment: Why `token.find("=")`, if you could do `if "=" in token`?

Comment: Indeed! I learned Python quite lately. Thanks for advice. I modified the code.